# Shift point into rectangle by shortest distance

Tags: algorithm

Given a rectangle defined by 4 points is there an algorithm to shift a point so that it lies inside the rectangle moving it the shortest distance.

I should have clarified the target rectangle has an arbitrary rotation. Also I am not so concerned with the translation vector I simply want to know which point within a arbitrary rectangle is closest to said point

Comment: By shift, do you mean translate?  Basically, it seems you want the shortest vector from the point to the rectangle.  Right?

Comment: Correct I want the point to lie within the bounding rectangle but I want to translate it along the shortest vector possible

Comment: Is the rectangle arbitrarily oriented or is is axis-aligned (a common case)?

Comment: Please edit the question

Comment: How is the rectangle defined?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest distance to move the point to the rectangle will either move the point to one of the corners or one of the sides (assuming the point isn't already inside the rectangle which you could test for like a bounding box).  So what you want to do is find the distance from the point to each of the segments representing the sides.  This is a point-segment distance and there are lots of places to find examples online.

Here's a clean example that only returns distance, but I've highlighted the three geometric cases of 1. Nearest to first point on segment 2. Nearest to second point on segment 3. Nearest to the side.

```
float dist_Point_to_Segment( Point P, Segment S)
{
   Vector v = S.P1 - S.P0;
   Vector w = P - S.P0;

   double c1 = dot(w,v);  // Point is closest to first point on segment
   if ( c1 <= 0 )
      return distance(P, S.P0);

   double c2 = dot(v,v);  // Point is closest to second point on segment
   if ( c2 <= c1 )
      return distance(P, S.P1);

   double b = c1 / c2;    // Point is closest to a side 
   Point Pb = S.P0 + b * v;
   return distance(P, Pb);
}
```

So you just have to do the above for each of the four sides of the rectangle.  You'll want to identify which case (1, 2, or 3) gave you the closest point.  That will give you the translation vector to the rectangle.

I should mention, there are optimizations you can make if you want to speed up your implementation.  For example, if you test two adjacent sides and you find that the closest point for both is the same vertex, then you can stop there because that must be the closest point on the rectangle to the point.